# Is there a way to get the current label name/id of a selected Mail?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I was wondering if its possible to get the current label name/id of the label the user selected in gmail.

I can get all labels a mail thread has, but I want to figure out which label the user currently looks at.

Maybe there is also a posiibility to parse the url of gmail in google app script? I know there is server side and client side but I dont have any other idea...

Thanks for your help
Anne

Answer (score 0):

Google Workspace doesn't have a feature to retrieve what email or label a user is currently looking at in their Gmail. This request can be promoted for future development through the [Google Workspace Feature Ideas Community](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Feature-Ideas/gh-p/workspace-ideas-group).

What you can do with the Gmail API is [list the messages in the user's mailbox](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list) and [list all labels in the user's mailbox](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.labels/list).